# 500 Internal Server Error using MongoLab + Rails 4 + Mongoid on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid, mlab

**The problem:**
Heroku responds me with this error after deploy & run from 'master':

> Dec 31 10:35:49 rsappqqsag app/web.1: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
>
> Dec 31 10:35:49 rsappqqsag app/web.1: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
>
> Dec 31 10:35:49 rsappqqsag app/web.1: Optionable::Unknown (:safe is an unknown option. Valid options are: :write, :read, :database, :max_retries, :pool_size, :retry_interval, :refresh_interval, :down_interval, :ssl, :timeout, :instrumenter.):
>
> Dec 31 10:35:49 rsappqqsag app/web.1:   app/controllers/bing_controller.rb:16:in `index'
>
> Dec 31 10:35:49 rsappqqsag app/web.1: Optionable::Unknown (:safe is an unknown option. Valid options are: :write, :read, :database, :max_retries, :pool_size, :retry_interval, :refresh_interval, :down_interval, :ssl, :timeout, :instrumenter.):
>
> Dec 31 10:35:49 rsappqqsag app/web.1:   app/controllers/bing_controller.rb:16:in `index'

**My stack:**

- Ruby 2.0.0
- Rails 4.0.2
- Mongoid

**My Gemfile:** http://pastebin.com/h9SiezJ8

**My mongoid.yml:** http://pastebin.com/TW8pswaw

I've done all the steps from ***devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab*** but nothing. The rails's app it's ok, runs with normality but when I call a function which connect with Mongo responds a 500 server error.

Thank you guys.

Comment: What is `app/controllers/bing_controller.rb:16:in 'index'` doing?

Comment: From the error mentioning ":safe is an unknown option", I would suspect that there is a newer version of Mongoid on the server than your application code expects. The `:safe` option was removed in [Mongooid 4.0.0](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and replaced with `:write`.

Comment: Yeah Stennie! of course! I don't know why I didn't see it before! maybe for many working hours.

Your answer helped me a lot, how I mark your answer like "winner"? 

Btw "jdl" thanks for trying!

Comment: This is why you don't post links to code without actually posting the code. Your links do not work so this post will never help anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stennie has solved the problem with the comment above:

> From the error mentioning ":safe is an unknown option", I would suspect that there is a newer version of Mongoid on the server than your application code expects. The :safe option was removed in Mongooid 4.0.0 and replaced with :write.

Solution (in my case): remove and/or change on mongoid.yml

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
      options:
        safe: true
        skip_version_check: true
```

To

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```